# Assistance with LINQ query spanning multiple tables with different relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6

I have the following problem to resolve and would like some assistance in the best way forward.

I have attached an image showing the setup of 4 tables (EF has removed the linking tables for some many-to-many relationships).

A brief overview of what I am trying to obtain via a `LINQ` query:
(I try to use method syntax). The system will allow users to submit a post under a category (depending on if they can access the category) for review before it's displayed.  The categories have a top level parent theme hence the self-referenced table (but could expand many children in the future). Each post can belong to 1 or more categories, i.e a post can be about `sports` and `IT` (silly example, I know).  Each category can have one or more approvers. The `announcement_approver` table will record & be a process-based table where one or more of the approvers will have to record whether the post has been edited, denied approval or approved by them. This will set a flag in the `announcement_posts` table (hence the one-to-many).

What I need to obtain is a list of all `announcement_posts` that have not been approved/pending (false in status), broken up by the Parent > Child relationship for a particular approver (the where clause will be based on the username field in the `categories_approvers` table). Hopefully I have explained properly here.

I have tried a method to start at the `category` table, use .include for the the virtual `ICollections` of category(self-reference), `cat_approvers` & `announcements_posts`. Then I have tried to join `announcements_posts` to `announcements_approvers`.

I have failed to get this working properly. I did think about working backwards from the posts table and include the cat table and announcements_approvers, but I think it would be a sticky situation to join Category to Category and then the approvers.

Sorry, if I have waffled on a bit here.

[Db Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VlXV.png)
[Desired Output hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfpC6.png)

[Many to Many Category to Posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3ikN.png)

Edit:

Some code I am trying to start with but getting no joy. This does not include any where clauses so its essentially all categories with their children, posts, approvers, and approval_posts.  I feel I am getting myself tied in knots and need a reset :)

```
List<Category> res = db.Categories
    .Include(a => a.ChildrenCategories)
    .Include(a => a.Categories_approvers)
    .Include(a => a.Announcement_posts)
    .Include(a => a.Announcement_posts.Select(a1 => a1.Announcement_approvals).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: What is the LINQ query you have already tried?

Comment: You should really do something about your naming, I cannot figure out how annouments are linked to a category.

Comment: And where is Theme?

Comment: a sample code would be helpful

Comment: Hi,  the Theme is what I have referred to as the Parent.  In the Categories table its a record with a null value for parent_id.  There are also a 1..n number of announcement posts to any given category but as a particular post can be in 1 or more categories thats why there is many to many between posts and categories.  I am just trying to grab some sample code of where I have tried to start but its being a bit problematic at the moment.

Comment: Added some code I am trying to start with but inst working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the assistance ikwillem but I went for a different method and persisted with the entity framework & linq directly.

For anyone that's interested in my solution here it is. I followed the EF include methodology and with some trial and error using nested selects got the information I needed within.  I then then simply projected into a new Vm.  I have a few where clauses I have removed for simplicity.

```
var currentUser = Authentication.GetGlobalUserName();

  db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

                //this is working from posts back to categories.
                var approveposts = db.Announcement_posts
                    .Include(a => a.Categories)
                    .Include(a => a.Categories.Select(b => b.ParentCategory))
                    .Include(a => a.Categories.Select(c => c.Categories_approvers))
                    .Include(a => a.Announcement_approvals)
                    .Where(a => a.Announcement_approvals
                          .Any(b => b.approver == currentUser && a.approved == false)              
                    .Select(p => new PendingPostsVm
                    {
                        PostGuid = p.postGUID,
                        Topic = p.Categories.Select(cat => cat.name).FirstOrDefault(),
                        Theme = p.Categories.Select(cat => cat.ParentCategory.name).FirstOrDefault(),
                        PostTitle = p.title,
                        Catid = p.Categories.Select(cat => cat.id).FirstOrDefault(),
                        DateSubmitted = p.date_created
                    })
                    .OrderBy(s => s.DateSubmitted)
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have no link table for the many-to-many foreign keys this is extremely hard to write. If you have the possibility to change the datamodel, you should really do it (this model is terrible). You should introduce a "Announcement_Categories" or "Category_Announcements" table which only has two foreign keys to the category and announcements then this code should work:

```
var approveposts = 
    db.Announcement_Categories
        .Where(a => a.Announcement.Announcement_Approvers.Any() == false)
        .GroupBy(a => a.Category);

foreach (var categorygroup in approveposts)
{
    var category = categorygroup.Key;
    var posts = categorygroup.ToList();

    // Find parents
    var parents = new List<Category>();
    var parentcategory = category.Parent;
    while (parentcategory != null)
    {
        parents.Insert(0, parentcategory);
        parentcategory = parentcategory.Parent;
    }
    
    // Show data
    
}
```

If you don't have this option you should make models to store this information which you load with all

```
    db.Announcements.Where(a => a.Announcement_Approvers.Any() == false)
```

items. Let me know if you don't know how to do this.

EDIT:

Added the initialization:

```
var categorygroups = new List<KeyValuePair<Category, List<Announcement>>>();

var approveposts = db.Announcements
    .Where(a => a.Announcement_Approvers.Any() == false)
    .ToList();

foreach (var post in approveposts)
{
    foreach (var category in post.Categories)
    {
        var categorygroup = categorygroups.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Key.Id == category.Id);
        if (categorygroup == null)
        {
            categorygroup = new KeyValuePair<Category, List<Announcement>>(category, new List<Announcement>());
            categorygroups.Add(categorygroup);
        }
        categorygroup.Value.Add(post);
    }
}
        
foreach (var categorygroup in categorygroups)
{
    var category = categorygroup.Key;
    var posts = categorygroup.Value;

    // Find parents
    var parents = new List<Category>();
    var parentcategory = category.Parent;
    while (parentcategory != null)
    {
        parents.Insert(0, parentcategory);
        parentcategory = parentcategory.Parent;
    }
    
    // Show data
    
}
```